# Why intencity of electric component of EMW does not influence on energy of EMW?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy, photons

As a quantum mechanics tells, electromagnetic field is actually an oscillated photons. Energy of them is **E=ħω**. So, does it an energy of emw, and if yes why it doesn't depends on intencity of electric component(but, hmm.. intencity is an classic term, can we use it, when we talking about emw as a system of photons?).

If it doesn't, what is the dependence between intencity or frequency and energy of photon, and what is the dependence between energy of photon and patricle speed?

Comment: have a look at:  https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit on a basic conundrum of quantum mechanics. Namely, of the issue of quantization. In classical mechanics, the energy of an electromagnetic wave is indeed dependent on the strength of the Electric (and magnetic) field. Specifically, it's proportional to the square of the field amplitude: $I\propto \vec{E}^2 $ where $I$ is the intensity of the light, and $\vec{E}$ is the electric field. What physicists found in experimentation; however, is that no matter how strongly they turned up the intensity of light, light of low wavelengths could not eject electrons from a piece of metal. And no matter the intensity of light, the average kinetic energy of the electrons ejected remained the same. This is called the photoelectric effect. The explanation of this effect is that it is true that the total intensity of light is proportional to the electric field amplitude squared; however, light is also quantized in such a way that each individual particle of light (a photon) has energy which is proportional to the frequency only: $E=hf$ where this $E$ is the energy. So how can these two seemingly contradictory statements be reconciled? Well, the *intensity* of light actually **doesn't** refer to the energy of any individual photon, but the collective energy of all the photons (per unit time). So what you are doing by increasing the electric field strength and thereby increasing the intensity is you are actually just increasing the **number of photons**! But if no individual photon has enough energy to eject an electron, electrons don't get ejected from the metal no matter how many photons you shoot at the piece of metal. This is the explanation of the photoelectric effect for which Einstein got his nobel prize.

Comment: Seems to be very simple, but well, ok, thanks